# On usage of “What’s in a name?”

Tags: phrase-usage, quotes

The most famous quote from Shakespeare’s “Romeo and Juliet” appears to have a  more recent  and different usage according to McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

[What's in a name?](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+in+a+name%3F)

> Prov. The name of a thing does not matter as much as the quality of the thing.
>
> - *Sue: I want to buy this pair of jeans. Mother: This other pair is much cheaper. Sue: But it doesn't have the designer brand name. Mother: What's in a name?*

I am not very familiar with the above usage which appears to suggest  a different connotation from the original one, possibly a jocular one,

and the McGrow-Hill Dictionary appears to be one of the few, if not the only source  to cite this current usage.

Questions:

Is the above-mentioned use of the famous quote an AmE thing?

Given that the original
quote is from the 16h century, how recent and how common is this current variant?

Comment: It's exactly the same meaning as Romeo and Juliet: a rose would still smell as sweet whatever it was called. The mother is saying that jeans would still wear as well whoever made them. It might be a jocular usage of an old quote. Who am I to judge?

Comment: Gucci by any other name would fit as neat.

Comment: What exactly do you *think* the phrase means, if it doesn't mean what AmE says?  What is your interpretation?

Comment: *O Romeo, Romeo, wherefore art thou Romeo?* is surely much better known than *What's in a name?*

Comment: @Caleb - maybe, but that has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 3):

### It's exactly the same as the usage in the play.

> What’s in a name? That which we call a rose
>
> By any other word would smell as sweet.
>
> So Romeo would, were he not Romeo called,
>
> Retain that dear perfection which he owes
>
> Without that title.

"Call a rose something else, it still smells good. If Romeo had a new name, he'd still be just as perfect." ("Owes" in this case means "owns".)

Juliet is saying that a thing is good if it's good, not because it has a good name attached to it.  Similarly, a pair of jeans is good if it looks good and feels good, not because it has a particular brand name written on it.

Comment: No, it is not used in the same original sense here. The expression is now used mainly in reference to brands, possibly fashion brands, so there is a different story and usage in place.

Comment: @user240918 It's still not clear why you think the meaning is different. Also: what makes you think that "the expression is now used mainly in reference to brands"? Yes, that's the example given, but a) it means the same thing despite the different context, and b) no evidence is given to show that the example is the main usage, and c) there's just not much call for soliloquy from vine-covered balconies these days.